# A variety of mappings from color to grayscale

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to convert a set of color images to grayscale. I use ImageMagick:

```
convert colorimage.png -colorspace Gray bwimage.png
```

But for each image there are some features that vanish or become imperceptible after the conversion. For example, with an image of two colors:

```
convert -size 50x100 xc:lightgray xc:pink +append lgraypink.png
```

[image: gray-pink in color]

that is then converted to grayscale:

```
convert lgraypink.png -colorspace Gray lgraypink-gray.png
```

[image: gray-pink in B&W]

it becomes difficult to see the distinction.

I am looking for a color-to-B&W conversion that produces, say, three images corresponding to different mappings. The three images would then be offered to the user and they would be asked to choose one. How can I tweak the mapping to generate different B&W images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could *"ring the changes"* on the proportions of the various R,G and B components like this:

```
convert image.png -channel R -evaluate multiply .2 \
                  -channel G -evaluate multiply .5 \
                  -channel B -evaluate multiply .3 \
                   +channel -separate -compose add -flatten gray_253.png

convert image.png -channel R -evaluate multiply .3 \
                  -channel G -evaluate multiply .2 \
                  -channel B -evaluate multiply .5 \
                   +channel -separate -compose add -flatten gray_325.png

convert image.png -channel R -evaluate multiply .5 \
                  -channel G -evaluate multiply .3 \
                  -channel B -evaluate multiply .2 \
                   +channel -separate -compose add -flatten gray_532.png
```

So the first one creates a greyscale made of 20% of the Red, 50% of the Green and 30% of the Blue etc...

Another idea, if you are interested in differentiating colours (i.e. hues), may be to convert to HSL colorspace and discard the Saturation and Lightness, leaving just the Hue and then contrast-stretch that to the full range of black to white tones:

```
convert image.png -colorspace hsl -separate -delete 1,2 -auto-level result.png
```